# How to theme one specific Views 3 exposed filter form template and HTML?

Tags: 7, views

I know of two ways to theme views exposed filter forms in Views 3:

- Copy the file `views-exposed-form.tpl.php` in `sites/all/modules/views/theme` to your theme folder and edit the HTML directly
- Use `hook_form_alter` in your template file, for example:

.

```
   function yourtheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
     switch ($form_id)  {
       case 'views_exposed_form':
         # do things to the array
       break;
     }
   }
```

My problem is, I have different exposed filters on different views, and these approaches both hit all exposed filters equally. There's also nothing about exposed filters templates in the Theme Information on the views edit page.

How can I target these to one specific exposed filter on one specific view?

Views 3 with Better Exposed Filters (BEF) module, Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

### For the .tpl file

Views recognises files with names of the form `views-exposed-form--view_id--display_id.tpl.php`. You can also use less strict filenames of the form `views-exposed-form--view_id.tpl.php` or `views-exposed-form--display_id.tpl.php`.

While it's not addressed directly there, you can look up and copy-paste what these values should be by going to the view edit page, then Advanced > Theme > Information, then taking a suffix from an option under Display Output at the top.

For example, this is a view with machine name `products`, and I'm targeting its `page` display:

[image]

So the filename is `views-exposed-form--products--page.tpl.php`.

Other prefixes in the Display Output section can be used too, for example `views-exposed-form--products.tpl.php` would target all displays from the "products" view, including blocks or panel panes, while `views-exposed-form--page.tpl.php` would target all views pages.

### For template.php

You can put a condition on the form's HTML id, which is generated along similar lines, like this:

```
   function yourtheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
     switch ($form_id)  {
       case 'views_exposed_form':
         if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-viewid-displayid'){
             # do things to the array
         }
       break;
     }
   }
```

Or potentially even `switch($form['#id']){}` - but the original is written assuming you already have other uses of this hook based on `$form_id` for other forms.

Continuing with my previous example, it'd be `views-exposed-form-products-page`.

Note that this might need a different string if you've overwritten the form ID output anywhere, and there doesn't seem to be any way to target all displays short of something crude like `if(strpos($form['#id'], 'views-exposed-form-products') !== false){  }`

Answer (score 0):

Should you need to render individual filter fields with custom html use the code below

`<?php print $widgets['FIELD_ID']->label; ?> //for field Label
<?php print $widgets['FIELD_ID']->widget; ?> //for field widget`

Your FIELD_ID should be what you get in the bold html below :

`<div id="edit-flight-way-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-`**filter-field_flight_way_value**`">`